# Flash works ugly

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash, browser, midori

After updates last Friday (16.01.2015) I have started getting problems with all my browsers which use Adobe Flash player (Firefox, Midori etc).

Videos from Youtube, Vimeo, etc. are playing "laggy" in all resolutions. It looks like I have a slow internet connection, but Chromium with pepper-flash and smplayer (network play via ,<kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>) are working without any problems. I tried to reinstall Adobe Flash without success:

```
sudo apt-get purge adobe-flashplugin adobe-flash-properties-gtk
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin adobe-flash-properties-gtk
```

Also:

```
sudo apt-get purge adobe-flashplugin adobe-flash-properties-gtk
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
- Adobe flash 11.2.202.*

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issues. Chromium has playing flash content flawlessly, but Chrome was lagging so hard it was unusable.

Chrome comes with a flash plugin, so removing and installing flash plugins from your system won't change a thing on Chrome. In my case, the Chrome's plugin was in /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash.

Chromium in the other hand, uses the flash plugin installed in your system. You can check what flash plugin you are using in /etc/chromium-browser/default. I'm using pepperflash.

```
flashso="/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so".
```

To make flash usable on Chrome:

1. I backed up the content of /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash:

   ```
   mv /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/manifest.json ~/Desktop
   ```
2. Copy currently installed flash plugin to chrome folder, pepperflash-nonfree:

   ```
   cp /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/* /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/
   ```

Comment: It is not browser problem. It is problem with Adobe-flash. You described how to change pepper-flash in browser and not how to repair Adobe-flash.

Comment: Pepperflash is another flash player like Adobe-flash. I use Pepperflash because I find it smoother than Adobe-flash, but that's just my preference. 

You can check what flash plugin you are currently using on chromium, cat /etc/chromium-browser/default and pay attention to flashso="PATH-TO-YOUR-FLASH-PLUGIN/libpepflashplayer.so". You can follow my suggested step with "PATH-TO-YOUR-FLASH-PLUGIN" instead of "/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/".

Comment: Please read my question more attentively. Chromium works. But all other browsers(Firefox, Midori, Seamonkey) that using system flash working bad.

Comment: I don't know about Midori or Seamonkey, but Chrome comes with a flash plugin that doesn't work well. I fixed Chrome by replacing its flash plugin by the flash plugin I had in the system, pepperflashplugin. The same plugin Chromium was using and was working well.